# Does nl have a limit?

Tags: shell, macos-mojave

I have a file with over 3 million lines, but when I use the nl command, it seems to be limited to 6 digits, and rolls over every million.  Is this a defect, or is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Did you read the `nl` man page? There's an option for it.

Comment: try --no-renumber

Comment: That is not an option on the Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it has nothing to do with restarting number, it is related to the width.

```
nl -w 10 MYFILE
```

works.